# Xamarin iOS how to implement a timer who could be use in two viewcontroller

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, timer

I need some advices, i made a small app with two view controller.
I have implemented a Timer in each view, but when i quit the second view with BackButton, i lose control on the Timer of the second view, and i am not able to stop it.

```
 public secondViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }
        public int Infset { get; set; }
        public double timeintervalle { get; set; }
        public int vtest { get; set; }
        public double Vconcentration { get; set; }
        public double Vpoids { get; set; }
        public double Vdose { get; set; }
        public double Vmltot { get; set; }
        public double Vresult { get; set; }
        public double Vnbmin { get; set; }
        public double Vnbsec { get; set; }
        public int vtest2 { get; set; }
        public int vtest3 { get; set; }
        public int button1status { get; set; }
        public int button2status { get; set; }
        public int mode { get; set; }
        public double EPSILON { get; private set; }

        Timer timer2 = new System.Timers.Timer();
```

Should i implement my two timer in appdelegate, if yes how?

```
public override void DidEnterBackground(UIApplication application)
        {
            // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers and store the application state.
            // If your application supports background exection this method is called instead of WillTerminate when the user quits.

        }
```

If some one could share an explample of code.

Thank you

Comment: Hello sorry i think i found one solution.

Comment: Maybe not the best one:     public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
        {
            timer2.Stop();
        }

Answer (score 0):

You can define `Timer` in `AppDelegate` ,and call it between all ViewControllers.

As we know , the class `AppDelegate` is singleton , we can initialize it in `FinishedLaunching`, start and stop when the ViewControllers comes visible or not.

```
//When the VC appear, start the timer.
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
    AppDelegate app = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate as AppDelegate;
    app.timer.Start();
}

//When the VC disappear, stop the timer.
public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);
    AppDelegate app =  UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate as AppDelegate;
    app.timer.Stop();
}
```